# How to customize a dialog's position, size and background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a home screen with a FAB and when it's pressed I want to display a dialog for user to input.

Currently I am using `showDialog()` with SimpleDialog.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      title: NormalText('New Counter Item'),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 0.0, 24.0, 24.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          ...
        )
      ],
    );
  }
);
```

But, I can't seem to customise almost anything with it (smaller, corner-curved and positioned lower on the screen). `AlertDialog` seems to be the same.

Is there anyway to customise those attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. These are not designed to be customizable. They were made to respect Material Design principles in mind.

If you want a custom design, you can make your own modal based of [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) and/or [`DecoratedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DecoratedBox-class.html)

Comment: I was wondering, isn't on [this talk](https://youtu.be/hA0hrpR-o8U) they advertised how easily everything can be customized for each brand to have their own design? Surely MD principles don't dictate something so basic like a dialog's corner radius.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what customizable means. They offer a few options. But ultimately if you want a radically different design, might as well create it anew. As this way you can remove the `import "package:flutter/material.dart"` from your project

Comment: I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container( height: 150, width: 150, ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Comment: Material doesn't have support for everything. It's just a base. Customization is key. I think this answer is a bit arrogant.

Answer (score 15):

```
return showDialog<void>(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: new Container(
                height: 100,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.purple,
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'custom dialog text',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

hope this helps,
thanks

Comment: I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container( height: 150, width: 150, ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Comment: @Kamlesh The dialog has default constraints. Move your dialog body to a ```UnconstrainedBox```.

Answer (score 11):

`SimpleDialog` and `AlertDialog` are meant to cater to a specific set of needs. They have certain levels of customization, but ultimately they are meant to just show simple pop-up dialogs that give the user some information and prompt for a dialog response (i.e. "Yes", "No", "Cancel", "Save", etc.).

If you want to have a more customizable pop-up dialog, you will need to create your own. On the plus side, though, it's really quite simple. Have the builder in `showDialog` return a `Dialog` widget with a child set to whatever you want:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext cxt) {
    return Dialog(
      child: Container(
        ...
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Obviously you are going to need to recreate things like the title bar and action bar, but you can either crack open the source code of `SimpleDialog` and `AlertDialog` and copy what they have there or you can roll your own solution.

Answer (score 9):

Despite what the accepted answer says; there are ways to customise the SimpleDialog in the ways that you have requested.

### **Size**

The SimpleDialog will grow in width/height depending on the child and how it is padded. The below code will generate a dialog of width 336 and height 300:

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

Not sure what the added 36 pixels to the width is; but this demonstrates that size *can* be customised.

### **Corners**

Corners can be customised using the `shape` property. The below code shows a green border with a rounded edge of 4 pixels:

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        side: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      /* ... */
    );
  },
);
```

### **Position**

I've found that I can nudge the dialog up and down the page by using the `insetPadding` property. This defines the minimum amount of space required between the edge of the screen and the dialog. Although it's a bit cumbersome, if you knew the size of the screen and the size of the dialog, you could nudge the dialog's position with some simple math.

Given a screen height of 1920px, and a dialog height of 300px, the below code should place your dialog 100px from the top edge of your screen, rather than bang in the centre:

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1520),
      /* ... */
    );
  },
);
```

This is because I've requested a minimum padding between the bottom edge of the screen and the dialog; and the only position for the dialog to exist under this stipulation is nearer the top.

Comment: I want to create a showDialog of 150 x 150 pixels fixed size. I have updated container width and height as return Container( height: 150, width: 150, ); but still not working. I am getting 3:2 ratio rectangle box instead of square share. any suggestion.

Comment: @Kamlesh As mentioned in the answer, Flutter seems to add extra width to the dialog. I'm not quite sure why this happens, but you could probably still trick the layout into showing a square dialog by removing some pixels from your stated width. Not ideal but unfortunately I don't have time to research the discrepancy.

Comment: Honnestly those are all hacks, might as well use your own dialog at that point

Comment: @Ced Honesty is good but I think it’s debatable whether these are _all_ hacks. The easiest code to maintain is no code, so if these achieve exactly what somebody wants then it doesn’t make sense to write something from scratch. So it depends on the individual circumstances.

Comment: Code that does not scream its intent is harder to maintain

Comment: @Ced And intent can dwindle when there are more lines of code. Building your own dialog will add more code surface area, which _may_ mean more places for bugs to hide and more maintenance. It may well be that writing something from scratch is a better option for a lot of people who are wanting to implement other features. I was just trying to provide possible solutions within the tools already given. I don't think your point is invalid, I just think it's context-dependant.

Answer (score 5):

It's not as scary as you might expect.
You only need to clone Dialog.dart, and
replace the Center widget with an Align.

Of course also rename stuff; e.g.  MyDialog, myShowDialog, MySimpleDialog.

Yep, it's that easy.

And if you're on a roll, how about adding the Align widget's alignment parameter as an extra...

Comment: In fact, it would be nice if the team were to add AlignedDialog to dialog.dart to save us the bother ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually modify it's position (only height) by adding a `SingleChildScrollView()` in the builder + a padding (for the offset from the top) as follows:

```
showDialog<String>(
  context: context,
  builder: (ctxDialog) =>
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150.0),
        child: AlertDialog()
      )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean solution, If for some reason you have a `TextField`/`TextFormField` and in there you have a `onsubmit` property then you can follow:

```
onSubmit: () {                   
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () { return Future(() => false); }, // this will prevent going back 
          child: AlertDialog(
            content: Row(
              children: [
                progressWidget(),
                Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),child:Text("Loading" )),
              ],),
          )
        );
      }
    );

    yourCallToMethod.whenComplete((){
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
},
```

**BENEFIT?**

When the `showAlert` is shown if someone tap on the screen randomly or aggressively then the screen goes back. This prevents that behavior and only closes the `showAlert` when your function completes.

Comment: You can use `showGeneralDialog<T>` function and set `isBarrierDismissible: true` to prevent users from closing the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61499567/how-to-change-the-position-of-a-dialogue-box-flutter). Thanks to @CopsOnRoad

[image]

Using `showGeneralDialog`

```
Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      showGeneralDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierColor: Colors.black54,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        barrierLabel: 'Label',
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: FlutterLogo(size: 150),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

:-  we can change vertical position of dialog boxes by give bottom
insetPadding like

```
insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: XX);
```

:-  And horizontal position by Horizontal padding or left

```
insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:XX);
or
insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: XX,right:YY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 showGeneralDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: true,
                pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
                  return Dialog(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Solved that with wrapping dialog body in `Stack` and `Positioned`

```
Stack(
                        children: [
                          Positioned(
                            left: 100, // left coordinate
                            top: 100,  // top coordinate
                            child: YOUR_DIALOG....
```