# How to change the position of a dialogue box Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a dialogue box which displays when a number exists in Firestore when registering a new user. However by default Android seems to be positioning the dialogue box in the center of the display. Is there a way to position the dialog box lets say at the position of the widget in which its called from , for my case it the Raised button call back.
Also would like to know how I can display from validation message in a pop just above a button,

Below is a sample of my code.

```
  numberExistsDialog(BuildContext context) {
var numberDialog = AlertDialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
  title: Text(
    'Number Already Exists',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
  content: Text(
    'Use another number',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ),
);
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return numberDialog;
    });
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if It can be done with the existing AlertDialog, but I have once changed the alignment of Dialog by making a custom dialog.

You can Use `Align` widget and align your dialog widget as per your need.
Here in example i am setting it to the `bottomCenter` that is `Alignment(0, 1)`.

Example code:

```dart
Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0, 1),
      child: Material(
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Number Already Exists',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Text(
                'Use another number',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

> PS: You can set the TextStyle according to your need as
>   `AlertDialog`'s `title` and `content` TextStyle is set by default from
>   the Flutter itself.

**EDIT:**

You can use it like below:

```dart
numberExistsDialog(BuildContext context) {
    var numberDialog = Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0, 1),
      child: Material(
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Number Already Exists',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Text(
                'Use another number',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return numberDialog;
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Use `showGeneralDialog` which comes out of the box with Flutter.

```dart
Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      showGeneralDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierColor: Colors.black54,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        barrierLabel: 'Label',
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: FlutterLogo(size: 150),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize it by your self which [here](https://github.com/YYFlutter/flutter-custom-dialog/blob/master/lib/flutter_custom_dialog_widget.dart) is a sample code. Or just use the packages. Here is a cool one:

[flutter_custom_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_dialog)

[image][image][image][image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `showGeneralDialog` if you want to animate the dialog or `showDialog` to simply to show the dialog, what you need to do is just change the alignment property for `Dialog`. Here is the example:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:freakfitness/utils/dimens.dart';

class CustomToast extends StatefulWidget {
  String? message;

  CustomToast({this.message});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CustomToastState();
  }

  void show(BuildContext context, String message) {
    showGeneralDialog(
        context: context,
        pageBuilder: (ctx, a1, a2) {
          return CustomToast(message: message);
        },
        transitionBuilder: (ctx, a1, a2, child) {
          return SlideTransition(
              position:
                  Tween(begin: Offset(0, -1), end: Offset(0, 0)).animate(a1),
              child: child);
        },
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 700));
  }
}

class _CustomToastState extends State<CustomToast> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: kToolbarHeight),
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding_large),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
        child: Text(
          widget.message ?? "",
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .subtitle2
              ?.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ScreenShot:
[image]